# Software to convert video to image sequence beside QT?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I want to convert a bunch of videos to image sequence with user defined intervals, but I don't have an export to image sequence option on my QUicktime player.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I find it frustrating that questions like this exist on stack overflow, but do not show up on google -- oh well, long after my project had become old, I stumbled across this gem: http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html

Works on Mac OSX Lion (and I assume it has compatibility with older versions of mac of course) -- I would get the beta version, it's more up to date and as of the writing of this answer, seems to be stable.

To export to image sequence (amongst other fun things such as zoom or rotating), go to: "File > Export to Other Formats...", then at the top there should be a format dropdown, one of the options being "Image Sequence"

When you click done, you are given the option to select a file name. Each of the image files will be that file name with a space and the sequence number appended (however you may disable the adding of a space in the export settings). The sequence numbers start at 1.

I realize this question is nine months old, but I am answering it more for prosperity -- hopefully people will be able to actually google for the answer to this question now, instead of aimlessly wandering the internet until they stumble upon a solution.

Up voted for good question with had to find answer :)

Other software that can do this:
Quick time 7 pro
kdenlive (extremely tedious format system, I suggest using ffprobe -show_streams to find out the avg_framerate (will be expressed as a fraction))

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 0.1 %06d.png` saves a frame every 10 seconds. It always includes the first few frames for some reason.

`mplayer -nosound -sstep 10 -vo png input.mkv` doesn't always stop at the end of the video.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few open source unix tools that can do what you want: https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-convert-video-to-images

You might need to use Terminal though.